# Null Pointer Exception in my dashboard system

Tags: java, mysql, jsf

I am doing something like twitters dashboard system for improving my Java Faces knowladge.I have problem that called dashborad.I need publish post in index to show who followed by logged user.Like Facebook's wall or Twitters dashboard.I have done something.But I have a error.Its a NullerPointerException.Here is my codes in down:
This is my model codes.It's a getting followers from database.

```
public void whoIFollow(int[] list) throws SQLException {
  MembersModel person = new MembersModel();
  person.LoggedUserInfo(person.getSession());
  long userid = person.getId();
  Statement stat = (Statement) getConnect().createStatement();
  ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `following` WHERE `follower_id`="+ userid); // Sorting following table which equals Logged Users id
  int i = 0;
  while (result.next()) {
    list[i] = result.getInt("user_id");
    i++;
  }
  if (i == 0) {
    System.err.println("i sıfıra eşit");
  }
}
```

Here is my getPosts method in Dashboard class:

```
public List<BlogPost> getPosts() throws SQLException {
        FollowingModel test = new FollowingModel();
        FollowingBlog post = new FollowingBlog();
        try {
            test.whoIFollow(followingList);
            String following = null;


            for (int i = 0; i < followingList.length; i++) {
                if (i == followingList.length) {
                    following += followingList[i];
                } else {
                    following += followingList[i] + ",";
                }
            }
            post.listPost(posts, following);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.err.println("Hataa");
        }
        return posts;
    }
```

1. **I have followingList integer array in DashBoard class **
2. **Also, posts ArrayList in DashboardClass**
   What is my mistake?

**Thanks for helping**
***Best Regars***

Comment: Can you change `System.err.println("Hataa");` to `System.err.println(e)` and post the stack trace?  That will tell you exactly where the NPE is occurring.

Comment: Unrelated to the NPE, but `if (i == followingList.length)` will never be `true` because the loop exits after `length-1`.

Comment: `SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Models.FollowingModel.whoIFollow(FollowingModel.java:116)
 at DashBoard.getPosts(DashBoard.java:48)`
This error gives when the cahgen error print.Also changed the if statement length-1 but problem is continoue

Comment: @KaanAlvésKılıç you're supposed to edit your question and add this information. The problem looks like `int[] list` parameter in `whoIFollow()` method is null. Also, it would be good to post your Managed Bean and its scope to see further errors (don't post all your code, just the relevant parts for this problem). Plus, add the JSF version you're using

Comment: I thinked it might be about each methods sir

Comment: I fixed my problem with more easier and simplicity.I was not need to use these method because I do this witj mysql JOIN attiribute.It was fixed all of my problems.But I had to write this method again.